# How to send a python requests post for an equivalent curl command?

Tags: python, curl, splunk

Hi

Following curl command works and am trying to post the same (with a different JSON data )using `requests.post` and running into below error shown,any guidance on what is wrong?

```
curl -vk "https://splunk-hec.company.com:8088/services/collector" -H "Authorization: {token id }" -d '{"sourcetype": "source","index":"indexname", "event": {"a": "value1", "b": ["value1_1", "value1_2"]}}'
```

PYTHON CODE:-

```
_raw = {

    "Total_radar_count":"999",
    "Analyze":{
        "Screen":{"count":110,"radar_link":"change://problem/50411162&42639456&44776863&43703933"},
        "Investigate":{"count":065,"radar_link":"change://problem/50411162&42639456&44776863&43703933"},
        "Review":{"count":106,"radar_link":"change://problem/50411162&42639456&44776863&43703933"}
    },
    "timestamp": int(time.time())  # Can also use datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
}
url = 'https://splunk-hec.company.com:8088/services/collector?sourcetype=source?index=indexname'
json = _raw
auth_token = 'token id'
head = {'Authorization': auth_token}
response = requests.post(url, json=json, headers=head)
print(response)
print (response.reason)
print(response.json())
```

ERROR:-

```
<Response [400]>
Bad Request
{u'text': u'No data', u'code': 5}
```

Comment: The urls are different.  Why does the python url have two question marks?

Answer (score 0):

400 (Bad Request) can be many things; see the doc at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400 . Next debugging step is to get out wireshark and look at the difference between the two requests. Obviously your data is different between the two, so it could be rejecting it just based on what it expects.

Also check the server-side log. Chances are the real error is in there.

Comment: So,you don't see anything wrong in the way i am sending the JSON data?

Comment: No, you're sending _something_, or you wouldn't be getting that 400 back.

Comment: even with the same data `{"a": "value1", "b": ["value1_1", "value1_2"]}` I get the same error,so am thinking am doing wrong at my end

Comment: Can you see the server side?

Comment: I don't have access to server side logs but I am sure I am sending it wrong

Comment: So fire up wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/) and capture both outgoing requests and responses. You'll see the difference in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
requests.post(url, headers=head, data=json.dumps(json))
```

You also need to import json package but don't wory it is a built in package

Comment: That didnt help

Comment: Actually, i think it's something with your URL, if you see after services it ask for some parameters, which you can either  format the string (i think that you have to change after the first '?' for '&') or remove the end of the URL and pass as params

Comment: If you are going for string formating, yes like ?sourcetype={}&Index={}".format(sourcetype_param, index_param)

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old. However, I thought to share this as I think it may helpful others. Just try adding `"event":` for you json post data.

`response = requests.post(url, json={"event": json}, headers=headers)`